# Scala no running play instance testing

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I'm working on a Scala project with sbt and Play. I wrote some tests that do not use any testing frameworks. They worked before Play was added to the working code. Now that Play is included, trying to run them throws an error in the code that uses Play directly:

```
background log: error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
...
background log: error: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
background log: error:  at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
background log: error:  at play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(Play.scala:86)
background log: error:  at play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(Play.scala:86)
background log: error:  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
background log: error:  at play.api.Play$.current(Play.scala:86)
```

Is there a way to run my test code without having to rewrite it to utilize a testing framework?

Comment: What you need is not a testing framework, but code that does not use `Play.current`.